# Cleaning up my SQL code

Tags: sql, mysql

So I have a site that is now receiving 30k unique hits a day, and at this moment during the day of peak hours I am getting a lot of 'error establishing database connection' (it's a WP install if you haven't guessed).

Here is a quote from my host:

> The error that you included in your
>   support request seems to indicate that
>   something is wrong with the code and
>   the SQL query is not formatted
>   properly.  You would need to dig into
>   that.  We do not offer support for
>   third-party applications or custom
>   code.

Is there some "easy way" of pinpointing bad formatted/programmed code via Firebug or some FF extension? I am trying to find any other possibility than going through line by line and making this a five year plan.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you persisit application-to-database connections over time? Do you use connection pooling?

Answer (score 1):

If this *only* happens during peak hours it's probably got nothing to do with the SQL query. Probably the system is not responding fast enough.

Comment: i am tying now to find our ram usage stats...here is a quick shot running top (http://pastebin.com/1Ccng3nY) and i don't see any large resources...

Comment: here is a mem usage for right now at lowest views (http://pastebin.com/Bv40e4gm). i will post same info at our peak times today to compare.